# Place a Button next to a TextBox total 100% width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to place a Button next to a TextBox when the Button has a given width (throug it's value) and the Parent div also have a given width.
In the end the TextBox width + Button width should be the width of the parent div.

TestExample:

```css
#left
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#right 
{
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" id="left"/>
    <input type="button" id="right" value="AnyText"/>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you are not allowed to define the width of the button?

Comment: No i am not :( So I need JS? :(

Comment: You could use flexbox. Put display:flex; on the containing div.

Comment: Maybe you could use `<table>`, put textbox in one cell, button in the other. And set the width of the table 100%. I can offer the code if needed and if you don't mind using `<table>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```css
form { display: flex; }
input[type=text] { flex-grow: 1; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Button text">
</form>
```

Comment: do you know how to handle this problem that not the full text is shown: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t0f6xop7/1/)

Comment: Add a `size="1"` attribute to the text input.

Comment: works fine with a text input - what to do with a number input?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. Creating a new question is reasonable, if you'd like, for this more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Table was my thoughts too.. maybe this will do what you are hoping?

```css
#right {
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="left" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="right" value="AnyText" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify width property for the parrent element to set button width 100%. In you case if you modify your css as below, you will acheive what you want

```
div {
    width: 300px; }
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; }
#right  {
    width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this in mind. more of a bootstrap design.

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10; right: 100px; left:5px; 
}
.right {
    float: right
}
.input-group {
    display: table;
position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group-btn{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-control{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}


<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="button" value="AnyText"/>
      </span>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KnowledgeGuard/4q7uf14h/41/)